# Dynamic menu active not working? (if condition not working )

Tags: php, html, css

// start get page name

  //end

class="active"  href="index.php"> Home

class="active"  href="login.php">Login

class="active" >Faq

class="active" href="contact.php">Contact

!-- static menu here below -->
        Contact

Comment: How tell how you are defining `$pagename` ?

Comment: i am getting pagename in the $pagename variable

Comment: I'm asking for the method from which you are getting page name.

Comment: $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $pagename = str_replace('/linkweb-master/'," ",$page);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing **/project/** with a space and this will output filename like " index.php" with a preceding space.

```
$pagename = str_replace('/project/'," ",$page);
```

you need to replace it without any space like

```
$pagename = str_replace('/project/',"",$page);
```

this will output filename without space.